# Catching key depressions with a Thread associated with a JavaFX application

Tags: java, javafx, game-development

I've started programming a game with some friends for a project. We trying to make a fighting game and I was having a pretty hard time with concurrency in JavaFX.
How can I costantly listen to key depressions with an associated Thread without freezing the application?
Thanks in advance for your help and have a nice Easter!

Comment: `Platform.runLater(() -> method_of_other_thread());` should do the deal. This will "slide" any function into the application Thread. But think about costly methods properly so you don't slow down the UI thread. DO NOT interfere with the applicationthread from outside. Use Platform.runLater() or any other mechanism like a Worker, Animationtimer combined with a BlockingQueue etc. it depends on your implementation, and how heavy it is.

Comment: @Luxusproblem thank you for your answer. I admit I'm very ignorant about concurrency in Java. Can you suggest me some resource that could help me better understand that?

Comment: You don't need a thread for this at all. The FX Application Thread already listens for key presses (and all other events), and you can execute code in response to them by registering event handlers.

Comment: @James_D i know but since it will be a local 2 players game I thought about making a Thread for each player since the character moves are a bit complex

Comment: Presumably different key presses respond to different players; you can just register an event handler for each player.

Comment: @James_D but are you sure it won't be laggy?

Comment: You need to follow the usual rules of threading in JavaFX: don't perform long-running tasks on the FX Application Thread, and don't update the UI from a background thread. But that's a different issue to the one you're asking here.

Comment: @James_D ok thank you man. I'll try and let you know if it works for me. I admit I'm not so much into threading in JavaFX

Comment: Probably a good thing you're unlikely to need threads then ;).

Comment: @James_D Sorry if I bother you but for example what If I wanted to move my character in a diagonal direction since I would have to press two buttons simultaneously?

Comment: If you handle key pressed and key released events separately, you can keep track of which keys are down, and you'll be able to track movement horizontally and vertically independently. I just posted an example which does that.

Answer (score 2):

You typically don't need threads for something like this. The general strategy for a game (or simulation) in JavaFX is:

1. Define classes to represent the state of the game/simulation ("model")
2. Define event handlers that update the state of the same based on usr input (e.g. key handlers)
3. Use an `AnimationTimer` as the "game loop". An `AnimationTimer`'s `handle()` method is invoked each time the scene is rendered, so you can update the UI based on the state of the game and the amount of time elapsed since the last update.

Here's a very simple example, where a player simply moves around the screen. The player has observable `x` and `y` coordinates, `boolean` values indicating if it is moving in each of the four directions, and a `move()` method that updates the position based on those directions and the time elapsed.

```
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;

public class Player {
    private final DoubleProperty x = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    private final DoubleProperty y = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    private boolean up ;
    private boolean down ;
    private boolean left ;
    private boolean right ;

    private final double minX ;
    private final double maxX ;
    private final double minY ;
    private final double maxY ;

    public Player(double minX, double maxX, double minY, double maxY) {
        this.minX = minX ;
        this.maxX = maxX ;
        this.minY = minY ;
        this.maxY = maxY ;
    }


    private static final double SPEED = 100 ; // pixels/second

    public void move(double elapsedSeconds) {
        int horiz = 0 ;
        if (isLeft()) horiz = horiz - 1 ;
        if (isRight()) horiz = horiz + 1 ;

        setX(clamp(getX()+horiz * SPEED * elapsedSeconds, minX, maxX));

        int vert = 0 ;
        if (isUp()) vert = vert - 1 ;
        if (isDown()) vert = vert + 1 ;

        setY(clamp(getY()+vert * SPEED * elapsedSeconds, minY, maxY));
    }

    // return value "clamped" between minValue and maxValue:
    private double clamp(double value, double minValue, double maxValue) {
        if (value < minValue) return minValue ;
        if (value > maxValue) return maxValue ;
        return value ;
    }

    public DoubleProperty xProperty() {
        return x ;
    }

    public final double getX() {
        return xProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setX(double x) {
        xProperty().set(x);
    }

    public DoubleProperty yProperty() {
        return y ;
    }

    public final double getY() {
        return yProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setY(double y) {
        yProperty().set(y);
    }   

    public final boolean isUp() { return up ;}  
    public final void setUp(boolean up) { this.up = up ;}
    public final boolean isDown() { return down ; }
    public final void setDown(boolean down) { this.down = down ; }
    public final boolean isLeft() { return left; }
    public final void setLeft(boolean left) { this.left = left ;}   
    public final boolean isRight() { return right ; }
    public final void setRight(boolean right) { this.right = right ;}       

}
```

Here's a controller class that registers key listeners on a `Scene` to update the `Player`:

```
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;

public class PlayerController {

    private final Player player ;
    private final KeyCode leftKey ;
    private final KeyCode rightKey ;
    private final KeyCode upKey ;
    private final KeyCode downKey ;

    public PlayerController(Player player, KeyCode leftKey, KeyCode rightKey, KeyCode upKey, KeyCode downKey) {
        this.player = player;
        this.leftKey = leftKey;
        this.rightKey = rightKey;
        this.upKey = upKey;
        this.downKey = downKey;
    }


    public void register(Scene scene) {
        scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, e -> {
            if (e.getCode() == leftKey) player.setLeft(true);
            if (e.getCode() == rightKey) player.setRight(true);
            if (e.getCode() == upKey) player.setUp(true);
            if (e.getCode() == downKey) player.setDown(true);
        });
        scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, e -> {
            if (e.getCode() == leftKey) player.setLeft(false);
            if (e.getCode() == rightKey) player.setRight(false);
            if (e.getCode() == upKey) player.setUp(false);
            if (e.getCode() == downKey) player.setDown(false);
        });
    }
}
```

and a simple view that just renders a player as a `Rectangle`:

```
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

public class PlayerView {

    private final Rectangle view ;

    public PlayerView(Player player, Color color) {
        this.view = new Rectangle(50, 50);
        view.setFill(color);
        view.xProperty().bind(player.xProperty());
        view.yProperty().bind(player.yProperty());
    }

    public Node getView() {
        return view ;
    }
}
```

Finally, the application class. This creates two players, each with their own set of key bindings (first player: W=up, A=left, Z=down, S=right; second player: I=up, J=left, M=down, K=right).

The `AnimationTimer` simply invokes the `move()` method on each player, passing in the amount of time elapsed since the last update.

```
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Game extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        Pane gamePane = new Pane();
        gamePane.setPrefSize(800, 800);

        Scene scene = new Scene(gamePane);

        Player player1 = new Player(0, 750, 0, 750);
        player1.setX(200);
        player1.setY(400);
        gamePane.getChildren().add(new PlayerView(player1, Color.STEELBLUE).getView());
        new PlayerController(player1, KeyCode.A, KeyCode.S, KeyCode.W, KeyCode.Z).register(scene);

        Player player2 = new Player(0, 750, 0, 750);
        player2.setX(600);
        player2.setY(400);
        gamePane.getChildren().add(new PlayerView(player2, Color.CORAL).getView());
        new PlayerController(player2, KeyCode.J, KeyCode.K, KeyCode.I, KeyCode.M).register(scene);

        AnimationTimer gameLoop = new AnimationTimer() {

            private long lastUpdate = 0 ;

            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {

                // first iteration:
                if (lastUpdate == 0) {
                    lastUpdate = now ;
                    return ;
                }

                long elapsedNanoSeconds = now - lastUpdate ;
                double elapsedSeconds = elapsedNanoSeconds / 1_000_000_000.0 ;
                player1.move(elapsedSeconds);
                player2.move(elapsedSeconds);

                lastUpdate = now ;
            }
        };

        gameLoop.start();

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

You can easily add other entities here that are "autonomous", i.e. that move around via their own logic, rather than via use input.

[Here's](https://gist.github.com/james-d/8327842) a more extensive example which is a simulation (so all entities are autonomous).

Comment: I read all the code with attention and you seriously saved me ahahaha. I'm really grateful, thanks for the crystal clear explanation!!!

Comment: But doing it in the Application Thread, can be a problem. The decoupeling of "business/gamelogic" is really important, because as soon it comes to "difficult" calculations, for example with a colisiondetection with a lot of bodies, the application will become really slow. So typically the UI thread is only for updating the UI and it should update ONLY the UI, with modeldata from the "gamelogic thread". In simple "just for fun" applications this might be suitable, but with this will make it really hard to "refactor" the whole thing to make it more performant, when you make the UI logic*